# Работа с массивом строк

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня есть массив строк:

```
char str[][]={"AAA","bB","aAaA","a","aaaaa"}
```

Как мне сравнить эти строки между собой, размеры ведь у всех разные?

Comment: для начала хотя бы определитесь сами с тем, какой результат хотите получить.

Comment: Что-то у меня сомнения, что это скомпилируется... Но если вы укажите второй размер - нет вопросов. Но в чем проблема? Сравнивайте себе, скажем, `strcmp(s[2],s[4])`...

Comment: если размеры разные, значит и строки разные? или у нас юникод хорошо завезли?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char str[][6] {"AAA","bB","aAaA","a","aaaaa", "aaaaa"};

    int r1 = strcmp(str[4], str[5] );
    int r2 = strcmp(str[5], str[0] );

    return 0;
}
```